# How to add a disk to a Google Compute Engine instance with the gce_pd Ansible module?

Tags: google-compute-engine, ansible

I'm new to Ansible, but I have a working playbook that creates Google Compute Engine instances. I followed the Ansible section of [Compute Engine Management with Puppet, Chef, Salt, and Ansible - Appendix](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/google-compute-engine-management-puppet-chef-salt-ansible-appendix) to achieve this.

Now I would like to extend the playbook to add extra persistent disks to the instances I've created, so I'm following the [gce_pd module documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/gce_pd_module.html). However the problem I have is that the snippet of yaml given in the documentation is out of context of a wider playbook:

```
# Simple attachment action to an existing instance
- local_action:
    module: gce_pd
    instance_name: notlocalhost
    size_gb: 5
    name: pd
```

So when I try to include this snippet in my playbook I'm getting a syntax error:

```
The offending line appears to be:

    - local_action:
        module: gce_pd
^ here
```

The last time I had a syntax error similar to this was because I hadn't init-ed the submodules, as per the line below. But gce_pd is a core module isn't it, so should already be available?

```
git submodule update --init lib/ansible/modules/core
```

Here is the playbook I'm trying to run:

```
- name: Create Compute Engine instances
  hosts: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    names: www1,www2,www3
    machine_type: n1-standard-1
    image: debian-7
    zone: europe-west1-d
    pid: <PID>
    email: <EMAIL>
    pem: <PEM>
  tasks:
    - name: Launch instances
      local_action: gce instance_names="{{ names }}"
                    machine_type="{{ machine_type }}"
                    image="{{ image }}" zone="{{ zone }}"
                    project_id="{{ pid }}" pem_file="{{ pem }}"
                    service_account_email="{{ email }}"
      register: gce
    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      local_action: wait_for host="{{ item.public_ip }}" port=22 delay=10
                    timeout=60 state=started
      with_items: gce.instance_data
      - local_action:
            module: gce_pd
            instance_name: www2
            size_gb: 20
            name: www2-pd
```

I have also tried changing the relevant section to this too:

```
- name: Add a persistent disk to www2
  local_action:
        module: gce_pd
        instance_name: www2
        size_gb: 20
        name: www2-pd
```

Can anyone set me straight as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I've discovered that the problem was caused by tabs in the yaml.

When I replaced tabs, that existed before the most-indented lines in the gce_pd section, with spaces, the error no longer occurred.

I guess, for the purposes of interpreting the yaml, a tab counts as a single whitespace character. Which means it's not actually indented enough with respect to the `local_action` line (**EDIT**: Actually tabs are forbidden in yaml).

Also this issue in the ansible-modules-core project on github was helpful in determining what the syntax should be: https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/977

My playbook now looks like this ... and it works:

```
- name: Create Compute Engine instances
  hosts: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    names: www1,www2,www3
    machine_type: n1-standard-1
    image: debian-7
    zone: europe-west1-d
    pid: <PID>
    email: <EMAIL>
    pem: <PEM>
  tasks:
    - name: Launch instances
      local_action: gce instance_names="{{ names }}"
                    machine_type="{{ machine_type }}"
                    image="{{ image }}" zone="{{ zone }}"
                    project_id="{{ pid }}" pem_file="{{ pem }}"
                    service_account_email="{{ email }}"
      register: gce
    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      local_action: wait_for host="{{ item.public_ip }}" port=22 delay=10
                    timeout=60 state=started
      with_items: gce.instance_data

    - local_action:
        module: gce_pd
        instance_name: "{{ item.name }}"
        project_id: "{{ pid }}"
        pem_file: "{{ pem }}"
        service_account_email: "{{ email }}"
        zone: "{{ zone }}"
        size_gb: 20
        mode: READ_WRITE
        name: "{{ item.name }}-disk"
      with_items: gce.instance_data
```